# Writing data between certain strings in text file (last element error)

Tags: python

So I have several .txt files with over 500.000 lines in each.
In all of them I have section which I want to extract into their own .txt file.

For this I'm using the following code:

```
for i, structure in enumerate(structures):
    with open("data.txt", 'r') as f:
        structure_data = open('data_new.txt'), 'w')
        copy = False
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() == "Structure: {}".format(structures[i]):
                structure_data.write(line)
                copy = True
            elif line.strip() == "Structure: {}".format(structures[i+1]):
                copy = False
            elif copy:
                structure_data.write(line)
    structure_data.close()
f.close()
```

Here `structures` is a list of, yeah, structures I have.

So basically in each .txt file there are lines that says `Structure: <some structure in the structures list>`. And I now wish to extract the data between the two strings `structures[i]` and `structures[i+1]` in the data file. In my example above it does this, and I get new .txt files with the data I wanted, however, as I get to the of the .txt file I get the following error:

```
    elif line.strip() == "Structure: {}".format(structures[i+1]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

The reason for this, as I understand, is that for that last part of the .txt file, there are no "end" `Structure: <structure>` so it can't set `copy = False`.

As such I do get the .txt file output I want, but as you know, there is nothing worse that code that has errors. So is there a way to tell it that if there is no such "end line", then eveything is okay ?

UPDATE:
This is what the data in the `data.txt` could somewhat look like:

```
Structure: TR

Dose [cGy] Ratio of Total Structure Volume [%]
         0                       100
  0.100619                       100
  0.201238                       100
  0.301857                       100
  0.402476                       100
  0.503096                       100
  0.603715                       100
  0.704334                       100
  0.804953                       100
  0.905572                       100

Structure: SV


Dose [cGy] Ratio of Total Structure Volume [%]
         0                       100
  0.100619                       100
  0.201238                       100
  0.301857                       100
  0.402476                       100
  0.503096                       100
  0.603715                       100
  0.704334                       100
  0.804953                       100
  0.905572                       100


Structure: DY

Dose [cGy] Ratio of Total Structure Volume [%]
         0                       100
  0.100619                   88.2441
  0.201238                   76.4882
  0.301857                   64.7324
  0.402476                   52.9765
  0.503096                   41.2206
  0.603715                   29.4647
  0.704334                    17.707
  0.804953                   17.6784
  0.905572                   17.6499
```

So in the `structures` list I already have the structures are in this case `TR`, `SV`, and `DY`.

So in the `for line in f` loop I want to take the text/data between the `Structures: structures[i]` line and `Structures: structures[i+1]` and save it to a text file, and then do it until the `structures` list has been looped through. But as stated, when I get to the last part there is no end `Structures: structures[i+1]`, hence I get an error. This error is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Can you please include some sample input and output? I've read a few times and I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: Coming up in 2 sec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy solution would be to simply add a dummy `structure` to the end of `structures` that does not occure anywhere in the file. 
You could then write your loop like this:

```
for structure1, structure2 in zip(structures[:-1], structures[1:]):
```

This will loop over all pairs of consecutive structures.

Another solution (avoiding the use of a dummy structure) would be to replace

```
elif line.strip() == "Structure: {}".format(structures[i+1]):
```

with

```
elif i+1 != len(structures) and line.strip() == "Structure: {}".format(structures[i+1]):
```

The second part of the condition (which causes the error) won't be evaluated if the first part is false. If you decide to use this version, you might want to replace

```
for i, structure in enumerate(structures):
```

with

```
for i in range(len(structures)):
```

as you're not actually using the variable `structure` anywhere.

Comment: This removes the error yes, but it doesn't "take" the text/data between the last structure and then the end where there is no second structure...

Comment: @DenverDang Sorry I missed that. See the update, I hope this time it is what you want :)

Comment: The dummy thing was excellent, and maybe the most easy way to do it, imho :) It works now. Thank you !